# MySQL substitution

Tags: mysql, sql

```
        +-----------------------------+
        | tables                      |
        +-----------------------------+
        | Date                        |
        | IP                          |
        | Location                    |
        | UserAgent                   |
        +-----------------------------+
```

For simplicty assume that these four tables have only  two columns: ID(int), name(VARCHAR)

Then I have this table called access_log, where I store only IDs of items i have in other four tables

```
        +---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
        +---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
        | id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
        | ip_id   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | ua_id   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | path_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        | date_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
        +---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Let's say I want to select everything from this access_log table and replace  ids  with  column NAME  I have in four other tables.
How can I achive that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on all four tables:

```
SELECT      access_log.id,
            `date`.name AS date_name, 
            ip.name AS ip_name, 
            location.name AS location_name, 
            useragent.name AS useragent_name
FROM        access_log
OUTER JOIN  `date` ON `date`.id = access_log.date_id
OUTER JOIN  ip ON ip.id = access_log.ip_id
OUTER JOIN  location ON location.id = access_log.path_id
OUTER JOIN  useragent ON useragent.id = access_log.ua_id
```

Comment: Thank you. I used LEFT OUTER JOIN.